# Terminology used before defined

Tags: makeindex

Is there an easy way to list all appearances of all words in the text of a LaTeX document that occur before a makeindex entry for that word arises in that document? When we move text around in a document, we can find that we have moved the definition of a technical term later in the document than one of the instances of that term being invoked. We cannot completely automate the task of eliminating these errors, because the same term might have a technical meaning defined somewhere, but also a common meaning, and the common meaning might be the meaning intended in an instance occurring before the definition. Still, TeX could help by making a list of these, so we could check.